# Specify a condition for each time a variable increases by a specific amount

Tags: c

I am making a simple snake game, and this is a function to return a variable which specifies the speed of the snake used in another function. It works perfectly fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to pack all my if conditions into one? I want to make the return integer value of the function decrease by 25 every time the get_score() value increases by 20. The first three if conditions in my code are:

```
unsigned int get_speed(void) {
        if(get_score() < 20) {                  // spd increases by 25 as score gets higher (every 20 interval)
            return 600;
        } else if(get_score() < 40) {
            return 575;
        } else if(get_score() < 60) {
            return 550;
        }
}
```

Comment: It's simple arithmetic. Divide by 20, then multiply that by 25.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is of very poor quality.

Comment: @gsamaras well congratulations on your platinum quality standards... but this question is not really poor quality... a problem statement, a code sample. It's just a beginner question, thats all.

Comment: Yeah you are right @grek40, still though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your specific case, as Barmar stated in the comment, can be solved most elegantly with simple math, you specifically said "a condition for each increase".

```
switch(get_score()/20) {
case 0: return 600;
case 1: return 575;
case 2: return 550;
}
```

Note that in this case, I don't break after each case, because they're all returns. If your condition doesn't return, you must use one.

---

Based on a comment, I'll also explain why our approaches work. When dealing with integer types, your CPU will simply round off the extra digits. For example, "round down to the nearest 20" can be expressed as `x = x / 20 * 20`. For `0 <= x < 80`, `x/20` can only equal 0, 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Might be worth to have a few words about why Barmers approach works and is save to use... integer arithmetic is not simple math - else the suggestion wouldn't even work but would result in a steady decrease of result values for each score